# Question regarding Strong Principle of Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm currently studying Discrete mathematics from a book by Normal L. Biggs and i don't understand the thinking about an example on Strong Principle of Induction,

The example i need help understanding:

> **Prove that** 
>   $ 
> n^2 > 7n +1, \forall  n \ge 8
> $
>
> **Solution**
>
> *The result is true when n=8 because $8^2 =64$ and  $ 7 \times  8 = 57 $. 
>   Suppose it is true when $ n $ is any number $ k \ge 8 $, that is $ k^2 > 7k + 1 $.*
>
> $ (k + 1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 > (7k + 1) + 2k + 1 = 7(k + 1) + 1 + (2k-6) $
>
> Since $ k \ge 8, 2k - 6$ is an natural number and the last expression above is greater then $ 7(k+1) + 1 $. The induction is verified, and so the result is true for all $ n \ge 8 $

**And here comes the part i don't understand.**

I don't understand, shouldn't it be $ (k+1)^2 > 7(k+1) + 1 $?

Where does the the "$2k$" come from in $ (7k + 1) + 2k + 1 $ and how does it result in the prof? Could someone explain on a basic level on the thinking behind this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so we already have the base case ($k=8$), so we need to prove the inductive hypothesis.

We assume that 
$$k^2 > 7k +1$$
for some $k\ge8$: we now want to show that 
$$(k+1)^2 > 7(k+1) + 1.$$
We know that $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 > (7k+1) + 2k + 1$.  We can simplify this last expression to $9k + 2 = 7(k+1) + 1 +(2k - 6)$.  As the example remarks, $k\ge8$, so $(2k-6) > 0.$  Thus,
$$(k+1)^2 > 7(k+1)+1 +(2k-6) > 7(k+1) + 1 + 0,$$
or more simply,
$$(k+1)^2 > 7(k+1) + 1,$$
as was to be shown.

I'll also remark that this example only requires *weak* induction, since we only need to assume the $k$<sup>th</sup> holds to prove that the $(k+1)$<sup>th</sup> case also holds.

Answer (score 1):

Because we have :

> $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$

and, by *induction hypotheses* we have :

> $k^2 > 7k+1$.

Thus, "substituting" the inequality in the first equality, we get :

> > $(k+1)^2 > [7k+1]+2k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Study Induction again !

In this step you just know for every $l\leq k$ : $l^2>7l+1$.

Here one doesn't know anything about $k+1$ !

Then we have $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$ and apply "induction hypothesis" on $k$.